# Protractor - Drag and Drop for Drag-able Items Container

Tags: protractor

I was trying to use  browser.actions().dragAndDrop(dragElement, dropElement).perform(); but i couldn't able to find the elements from the page which i'm working on. The elements are placed in the below format and i'm wondering how to find one of the element and drag it to another side. Do anyone have an idea on this or faced similar task?

ANALYSISGENERIC_ANALYSISACTIONACTIONHRCHTYPECHTEMPCHDURATIONCHLIGHT

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you paste your code in to the question please rather than showing it as an image - this is about making it easy for people with limited time to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't able to find the elements or is the drag and drop just not working? If you are using chrome this is a known issue. Try using [html-dnd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-dnd) instead.